# PHPSlim + angular-file-upload

Tags: php, angularjs, slim, angular-file-upload

I use angular-upload-file with a server side built with PHP Slim Framework.
On my FileUploader config I simply have :

```
$scope.uploader = new FileUploader({
    url: 'upload/upload.php'
});
```

Then in my backend, like the related wiki does :

```
 if ( !empty( $_FILES ) ) {
    $tempPath = $_FILES[ 'file' ][ 'tmp_name' ];
    $uploadPath = dirname( __FILE__ ) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'uploads' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $_FILES[ 'file' ][ 'name' ];
    move_uploaded_file( $tempPath, $uploadPath );
    $answer = array( 'answer' => 'File transfer completed' );
    $json = json_encode($answer);
    echo $json;
} else {
    echo 'No files';
}
```

The problem is when I put this code without using PHP Slim it works fine, but when I try to wrap it with PHPSlim , I get a GET request instead of POST:

[image]

with a such code :

```
 $scope.uploader = new FileUploader({
    url: 'API/upload/img'
});
```

And into the API :

```
$app->post('/upload/img', function(){
if ( !empty( $_FILES ) ) {
    $tempPath = $_FILES[ 'file' ][ 'tmp_name' ];
    $uploadPath = dirname( __FILE__ ) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'uploads' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $_FILES[ 'file' ][ 'name' ];
    move_uploaded_file( $tempPath, $uploadPath );
    $answer = array( 'answer' => 'File transfer completed' );
    $json = json_encode($answer);
    echo $json;
} else {
    echo 'No files';
}
```

});

I try to figure out where the issue come from, server or client side ?
I tried to use a similar plugin ng-file-upload but I have exactly the same problem, so I think it should be PHPSlim but I am not sure.

I need to use PHPSlim because I use a middleware for some required authentication requests.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

First you need to call right address for the API:

```
var uploader = $scope.uploader = new FileUploader({
  url: 'api/path/upload'
});
```

in backend you need

```
 $app->post('/upload', function() {
      if ( !empty( $_FILES ) ) {... 
      }
 })
```

if you have problem with message response need to formatted I build on this way:

```
    $answer = array(
          'status' => 'success',
          'message' => 'File transfer completed',
        );
...
  echoResponse(200, $answer);
...
    function echoResponse($status_code, $response) {
        global $app;
        $app->status($status_code);
        $app->contentType('application/json');
        echo json_encode($response, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
    }
```

also create and set write folder permission for

```
$uploadPath = dirname( __FILE__ ) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'uploads' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $_FILES[ 'file' ][ 'name' ];
```

Comment: That's exactly what I used to do, the routes matches well but I don't have any POST request made with a Slim wrapper. I wonder if the plugin deal only with file and not routes

Comment: Add complete code in your controller and you will have the reports in the browser.
[angularFileUploadController](https://github.com/nervgh/angular-file-upload/blob/master/examples/simple/controllers.js).

Comment: Is you call right action?
Try to call in browser other API action, all working like a charm on my computer. You in right way... How you implement controller and how look your data structure (folders and files)?